How to analyse nominal and categorical vairablescontaining more than one responses
I am new on to R Programming
I have tried several codes to analyse the data below in a way that each question will have their responses stacked on each other in a bar chat to no avail
Cookies Pizza Strawberry
Very Familiar;     Familiar;        Not Familiar
Familiar;        Very Familiar;       Not Familiar
Familiar;        Not Familiar;       Very Familiar
Very Familiar;     Familiar;        Not Familiar
Familiar;        Very Familiar;       Not Familiar
Familiar;        Not Familiar;       Very Familiar
same with this analysis too
##employee role performance improvement
training program flexible work communication
Neutral;          Agree;        Agree
Disagree;        agree;       Agree
Neutral;        Disagree;       Agree
Agree;         Disagree;        Disagree
Disagree;        Agree;       Agree
Neutral;        Disagree;       Agree
Agree;         Disagree;        Disagree
rf<-r %>% select(Cookies,Pizza,Strawberry) %>% group_by (Cookies,Pizza,Strawberry)
rfp <- ggplot(data=rf, aes(x=Cookies,Pizza,Strawberry))

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput(). But it looks as if you simply need to reshape your data to long format, e.g. something like dat |> tidyr::pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") |> ggplot(aes(y = name, fill = value)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

tribble(
  ~Cookies, ~Pizza, ~Strawberry,
  "Very Familiar", "Familiar", "Not Familiar",
  "Familiar", "Very Familiar", "Not Familiar",
  "Familiar", "Not Familiar", "Very Familiar",
  "Very Familiar", "Familiar", "Not Familiar",
  "Familiar", "Very Familiar", "Not Familiar",
  "Familiar", "Not Familiar", "Very Familiar") |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "what", values_to = "how") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = what, fill = how)) +
  geom_bar()

